# Circular uiscrollview with list of items (buttons)

Tags: objective-c, ios, scrollview

I am trying to get the circular scroll with list of buttons, buttons width should be dynamic (not fixed). I tired with iCarousel, but the problem is it is accepting itemWidth as a static, which will effect all items in the carousel view. so some of the titles are overlapping, some are having too much space between them. I need that item width should be dynamic.

Could anyone help to do the same.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

iCarousel supports any dimensions in the views used to display each "card":

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
}
```

You will have to generate different views for each of your cards (and certainly cache them somehow).

Comment: If we set itemWidth to 100px, iCarousel will allocate 100px space for each card irrespective with the card/view size (width), which we are going to generate in viewForItemAtIndex method